# Python 2.7 list of dictionaries in memory between page trips

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

I researched up and down and I'm not seeing any answers that I'm quite understanding so I thought to post my own question.

I building a web application (specifically in web2py but that shouldn't matter I don't believe) on Python 2.7 to be hosted on Windows.

I have a list of about 2000 items in a database table.
The user will be opening the application which will initially select all 2000 items into Python and return the list to the user's browser.  After that the user will be filtering the list based on one-to-many values of one-to-many attributes of the items.

I'm wanting Python to hold the unadulterated list of 2000 items in-memory between the user's changes of filtering options.

- Every time the user changes their filter options,
- trip the change back to Python,
- apply the filter to the in-memory list and
- return the subset to the user's browser.

This is to avoid hitting the database with every change of filter options.  And to avoid passing the list in session over and over.

Most of this I'm just fine with.  What I'm seeking you advise on is how to get Python to hold the list in-memory.  In c# you would just make it a static object.

How do you do a static (or whatever other scheme that applies) in Python?

Thanks for your remarks.

---

While proofreading this I see I'm still probably passing at least big portions of the list back and forth anyway so I will probably manage the whole list in the browser.

But I still like to hear you suggestions.  Maybe something you say will help.

Comment: What makes you think storing it in web2py's `session` is different from storing it in "Python memory"? Those seem like the same thing to me, and exacty what `session` in web2py is for.

Comment: Is it the same thing?  Wouldn't the entire list of 2000 then be passed server-browser-server with every page trip along with the filtered down list?

Comment: Yes, but that is the nature of HTTP, it's stateless so you have to pass objects with every request/response. You could look into using memcached but it seems like overkill for your situation.

Comment: @voodoo-burger @Steve, web2py sessions are not stored in memory nor passed back and forth between the server and browser (unless you use the optional cookie-based sessions). By default, sessions are stored in files on the server, though optionally they can be stored in the database. The session for a given user is identified by an ID that is passed back and forth via a cookie. If you want to hold something in memory, you can use `cache.ram` or another memory-based caching system, though as noted, in this case managing the data in the browser is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to conclude, there isn't much reason to be sending requests back and forth to the server given that the server isn't generating any new data that isn't already held in the browser. Just do all the filtering directly in the browser.

If you did need to do some manipulation on the server, though, don't necessarily assume it would be more efficient to search/filter a large dataset in Python rather than querying the database. You should do some testing to figure out which is more efficient (and whether any efficiency gains are worth the hassle of adding complexity to your code).